# Show that the set of sequences of value in $\mathbb{N}$ is equipotent with the set of sequences of value in {0,1}

Tags: real-analysis

I'm really stuck on this problem. I couldn't find an injection or bijection from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ to $2^\mathbb{N}$ in order to apple Schroder-Bernstein. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and $2^\mathbb{N}$? Can you describe the sets?

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of sequences taking values in $\mathbb{N}$